# Installed Opencart theme not showing?

Tags: web-hosting, ftp, theme, opencart, installation

I've installed a few free opencart themes for testing before I pay for any themes. Only 1 worked successfully, ie, when I enable it, my website changes.

However, none of the 3 themes I installed shows up in the admin area under Systems --> Settings --> General tab "Theme" drop menu. You can see the screenshot below:

[image: Opencart 3.0.2 Admin Systems --> Settings --> General tab]

According to some tutorials I saw, your installed themes are supposed to show up here. One tutorial I saw says its supposed to be under the 'store' tab. There are no 'Theme' drop menus there.

However when I go to Extensions --> Modifications, 2 of the themes show up:
[image: Opencart 3.0.2 Admin Extensions --> Modifications]

The only one that appears on my site is the Dark Velvet one. The Purple tree multivendor does not work, even when enabled.

Install methods I've used:

For Dark Velvet and Purple tree multivendor, I used the step by step instructions in the video [here](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=35176&filter_category_id=20&filter_license=0&filter_download_id=55) on the Purpletree's theme download site. Dark Velvet has basically the same instructions [here](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=24286&filter_category_id=1&filter_license=0&filter_download_id=55&page=2) but in text and less detailed.

Both themes downloaded as ocmod.zip files. In order to use the extensions --> installer in the OC admin, the theme needs to have ocmod.zip extensions. I saw other instructions say to extract the files to your computer then use Filezilla to upload it by clicking and dragging the files from your computer to the web host folder under catalog --> view --> themes (see [here](https://opencart-training.com/installing-custom-theme#.W92Va9UzbIW)). I was able to do all the steps for a 3rd theme but it did not show up in OC admin or my site.

Notes:

I got a free hosting account and subdomain for testing from 000webhost.com and used Filezilla as my FTP software and I use Windows 7.

Comment: Perks of free hosting... waiting for someone to contribute. Within the control panel does it have a method of uploading the zip files within the Content Management System without using FTP?

Comment: Does it have a method for uploading ZIP files? Yes, if you mean the OC admin back end. You are supposed to go to Extensions --> Installer and upload just ZIP file with, as I said, the ocmod.zip, which I did. But other sources (outside of OC, say to unzip then use Filezilla, which I also did.

Comment: It could be a permission problem so look at your folders and the files within them, folders should be 755 and files 644, other than that I don't know but what I will say if you were using a good paid hosting platform this problem would have been sorted within mins.

Comment: @SimonHayter, can you explain what you say folders hsould be 755 and files 644? Is that the quantity of folders and files there are? And, as I said, I got a free one for testing to see if I am able to install it myself/what the user interface would be, so if you know it is a hosting thing, then just explain that. (Eg what makes a good host solve this problem)

Comment: No, 755 and 644 are Unix permission levels of folders and files, see http://permissions-calculator.org/ which should help you understand. If your having headaches now with your host you can only expect it to get worse when you actually have something wrong with a site that is ranked and has a community.